# For each object Javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach

hope all is fine for you
I'm a beginner in javascript and i'm trying to integrate a video customer review API on my website.
The integration is working on all my pages but on one product page i'd like to init the sdk for each videos id returned by the object to display all the video reviews of this product.

The sdk returned an object as below : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMM4O.png)

And i have to display the sdk like that :

```html
 SDK.init(
            {
                type: "player",
                args: {
                    key: playerKey,
                    id: videoId, // Id returned by the object on the screenshot
                    width: '100%',
                    height: "inherit",
                },
            },
            videoPlayer //=> my div element 
        )
```

i tried the for each method, objects as below but nothing work for me, each time only 1 player is displaying.

```html
 Object.keys(videos).forEach(id => {
        console.log(videos); 
        SDK.init(
            {
                type: "player",
                args: {
                    key: playerKey,
                    id: videoId,
                    width: '100%',
                    height: "inherit",
                },
            },
            videoPlayer
        )
      });
```

I have no archive what i tried before this but i'm a little bit lost

Have a nice day and thank you

Comment: *"the sdk"*: which? Can you link the API documentation?

Comment: You seem to have just one `div` you're reusing. I suspect the video thing needs a separate `div` for each instance.

Comment: Thx, so i have to createElement(div) in the condition ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation indicates that one HTML element should be dedicated to one player. So you cannot put several players in one element.

You could create child elements inside your container element.

Assuming that `videos` is an *array*, like depicted in the screenshot:

```
videos = [
    { id: '....' },
    { id: '....' }
]
```

then do this:

```
for (let {id} of videos) {
    console.log("video ID", id);
    const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    videoPlayer.appendChild(wrapper);
    SDK.init(
        {
            type: "player",
            args: {
                key: playerKey,
                id,
                /* any other properties you want to add here */
            },
        },
        wrapper
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot, it work but i have an other issue now, the player is sometimes duplicating the player for the same video id

Comment: i tried to set a if(videoId2 != videoId) But this is not working because a blank area replace the second/third players

Comment: What is `videoid`? It doesn't occur in my answer. Nor `videoid2`.

Comment: To display each player with a unique id and brain duplication, i added videoId = videos[0].id and a videoId2 with same value

Comment: I don't understand why you do that. The `id` in the loop is taken from the `videos` array already, and is passed on to  the `init` function. Why would you change that?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try the SDK, but as @T.J. Crowder mentioned in the comment you probably need to create new `<div>` for every init call, something like this:

```
 Object.keys(videos).forEach(id => {
        console.log(videos); 
        const node = document.createElement("div");
        node.style.width = '500px';
        node.style.height = '500px';
    
        videoPlayer.appendChild(node)

        SDK.init({
            type: "player",
            args: {
                key: playerKey,
                id: videoId,
                width: '100%',
                height: "inherit",
            },
        }, node)
      });
```